# Is it a bad idea to have a composite primary key that contains a foreign key?

Tags: database, foreign-keys, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I am designing a database and have the two following tables:

- `t_model` (with fields: `model_id` (PK), `model_name`)
- `t_model_version` (with fields: `model_id` (PK, FK), `model_version` (PK), `start_validity_date`, `end_validity_date`)

As one can see, `t_model_version` its PK is a composite PK. One of the fields part of the PK is also a FK (the PK of `t_model`). I was wondering whether this is good or bad practice? I would like to avoid getting into difficulties later on that I cannot yet foresee...

`t_model` holds different models (e.g. different models/functional forms to predict macroeconomic growth). `t_model_version` holds the version numbers per model (e.g. a different version  of a model means that the functional form is kept but that the coefficient estimates have been updated).

*Edit:* My question is not about **how** to add a FK when the field of interest is already part of a composite PK, but whether this a good practice. Hence, my question is not a duplication of [Composite Primary Key + Foreign Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11215494/composite-primary-key-foreign-key).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Composite Primary Key + Foreign Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11215494/composite-primary-key-foreign-key)

Comment: Please always before you post google many clear, concise, specific versions of your question. (If you still ask, use one as your title.) Here I answered because I didn't find a clear duplicate I liked right away, but googling the end of your title gives lots of reasonable of hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest problem is if the FK field could also be null in your data because it could cause uniqueness issues. However, given your field structure, I would find it unlikely that you would allow nulls in that field in any event.

Answer (score 1):

Just declare them where you find them so the DBMS can enforce them--unless already implied by other declarations--except you must declare a `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE NOT NULL` column list that is referenced by a `FOREIGN KEY`.

Declare a `NOT NULL` when a column can't be NULL. Declare a `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE NOT NULL` when subrow values are unique and not null (and don't contain a smaller such subrow, which would imply that). Declare remaining `UNIQUE` subrows (that don't contain smaller ones, which would imply that). Declare a `FOREIGN KEY` when subrow values must appear elsewhere as `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE NOT NULL` values (and a chain of `FOREIGN KEY`s doesn't already say so). Then if necessary declare remaining subrows referenced by `FOREIGN KEY`s.

PS There's no use worrying about every combination of notion that you learn. Read about information modeling and relational databases to learn good design.

Answer (score 0):

That's fine--common, even--if you are using natural keys.  It's unnecessary if you're using surrogate keys.

Comment: If surrogate keys are used, the child table won't have the natural keys of the parent, only a foreign key equivalent to the (surrogate) primary key of the parent, but that *won't* be part of the primary (surrogate) key of the child.

Comment: I'm just trying to make sense of you saying something is unnecessary when it's impossible/irrelevant. I could understand "becomes unnecessary". Except anyway here if you had a t_model_version surrogate you would still need to relate that to its t_model_id & version, so there's still a composite CK containing a FK. Your answer is so terse it's unclear. Also, model_id already *is* a (user-visible) surrogate.

Comment: If you are using a surrogate key as the PK of your model_version table (i.e., a single autoincrementing column) then, because it is a single column, it will not contain the FK into your model table.  So read "unnecessary" as 'unnecessary concern'.  And by the way, I am not necessarily recommending the use of surrogate keys in this case.

Comment: Your last comment does not address anything in my last comment.

Comment: If surrogate keys are used in both tables (and the OP did not say that `model_id` is a surrogate key), then the FK from the `t_model_version` table is only a single column (`model_id`) that is not part of the PK of the `t_model_version` table--therefore the PK of the `t_model_version` table is not composite.